# how we use product duplicate observer event at custom module?

Tags: magento

This is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Document   : config.xml
    Created on : July 26, 2012, 1:12 PM
    Author     : sanjeewani
    Description:
        Purpose of the document follows.
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Proporta_AmazonBarcode>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Proporta_AmazonBarcode>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <catalog_model_product_duplicate>
                <observers>
                    <proporta_amazonbarcode_observer>
                        <class>Proporta_AmazonBarcode_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>duplicate1</method>
                    </proporta_amazonbarcode_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_model_product_duplicate>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

and this is my Observer class function.

```
public function duplicate1(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

      $product=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
/*
my logic is here
*/

    }
```

It's coming properly to duplicate1() function when I try to duplicate the product from admin.
My problem is, $product is null. I can't get product from event. Anyone have an issue like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `product` is not a key of the event context. If you are unsure, what the context is, it's a good idea to look where the event is dispatched[1]. In this case in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php` in the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::duplicate()`:

```
    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'catalog_model_product_duplicate',
        array('current_product' => $this, 'new_product' => $newProduct)
    );
```

So, what you probably want to do is this:

```
  $product = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrentProduct();
```

[1] or use a debugger, place a break point and inspect `$observer`

Comment: thank you very much fab. Actually i don't want to get current product but i need new product.this is what i have done before. and this work for me.
$evet['new_product']['amz_barcode_type']=$this->merchand_id_type;
$evet['new_product']['amz_barcode']=$this->getNewAmazonBarCodeValue();

but your way is proper than my way.
 
But i got the point from your post.
 $product=$observer->getEvent()->getNewProduct();
 $product->setAmzBarcodeType('')
         ->setAmzBarcode('');

Answer (score -1):

You have to put product ID , without ID , it wont work. When it comes to debugger , get HTTP Debugger , put BP , and observe response and everything that could look suspicious.